# How to store PathGeometry?

Tags: c#

I have several PathGeometry-s which are showing line between places. I want to save these lines. I couldn't serialize it to XML and don't know how to store these lines. Is there any chance to do it ?

[EDIT] I have PathGeometry-s at code behind, not in XAML. When i try to use XMLWriter class to store these it gives exception "... classes couldn't be restored because they dont be known as known types  "

Comment: see edit, is this what you´re looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have the PathGeometry already instantiated as an object you can try to use the XAMLWriter to serialize it [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx)

e.g.

```
        var pathgeo = new PathGeometry();
        pathgeo.AddGeometry(new PathGeometry(new PathFigureCollection() { new PathFigure(new Point(10, 50), new List<PathSegment>() { new LineSegment(new Point(200, 70), true) }, false) }));

        // Save
        var s = XamlWriter.Save(pathgeo);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        // Load
        var ob = XamlReader.Load(stream);

        // test beeing a System.Windows.Shapes.Path
        test.Data = ob as PathGeometry;
```

Comment: thank you. it is what i was searching. And last question, which is the best, to restore this as byte array, or as xaml text in SQL database ?

Comment: I think this depends on whether you need the comfort of beeing able to modify the values easily in your db. For perfomance questions binary vs char, consider opening a new question on SO

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize `PathGeomety`-s string representations in collection and when you want to restore it , use this  great solution to restore

http://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com

There is method StringToPathConvertor.Convert(string path) which returns PathGeometry.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you store it to xml? What about `<Line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>`? Maybe you can give a little example?